# InputStream never gets EOF

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, eof

Before anything, allow me to show you my client code:

```java
                    String command;
                    socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            final byte[] targetArray = new byte[is.available()];
                            final int x = is.read(targetArray);
                            if (x == -1) {
                                System.out.println("end");
                                break;
                            }
                            if (x == 0) continue;
                            command = new String(targetArray);
                            handleCommand(command).start();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

once connected to the actual socket, the client sends out some authentication data, but doesn't recieve any data, now, it waits to recieve data from the server, and when it does, it processes it fine etc, except, when I stop the server (literally shutting down the program), nothing happens, when in reality, im expecting it to send EOF (-1). Instead it just spams out 0 consistently.

Comment: When the stream reaches the end, there are 0 bytes available, so you keep trying to read 0 bytes forever which always immediately exits after reading 0 bytes. You should instead use a buffer of some useful size like 4096.

Comment: It says right in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D,int,int)) : "If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned;"

Comment: Also, not all subsequences of byte encodings of strings are valid, so that assumption of your code is incorrect. Also, assuming that the exact bytes that were written in one operation at the peer will be read in one call at your end is incorrect. Also, always specify the character encoding when encoding/decoding strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`available` method's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--) (emphasis mine):

> Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read ...

and

> It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream ...

So according to the minimal code you posted, you shouldn't use `available` to allocate the buffer, because it may always return `0` which in turn makes the `read` operation always return `0`. But according to your question you only see this behaviour when the sending program is closed which should mean that:

1. The `available` method correctly returns the buffered number of bytes in the stream, so this is why you receive the data. Even if you consume received data faster than the sending end sends (so some zeros may show up in `available`) you just `continue` and never handle that case, which makes some other loop in the future to capture the (eventually) received non-zero length data.
2. Once the sending end is closed, there will be a point after which it will always return `0` since it has no data. So you allocate zero length buffer, and the `read` method first checks that your buffer is zero length, rather than EOF.

So make sure the allocated buffer is of size at least `1`.

Also, according to the [`Socket#getInputStream` method's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream--):

> If there are no bytes buffered on the socket, and the socket has not been closed using `close`, then `available` will return 0.